# Pip commands in Kaggle create a lot of dependency resolver issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have been using Kaggle for training models. I have a notebook in which I ran this command `!pip install -Uqq fastai` and it output this error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-io 0.21.0 requires tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.21.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow 2.6.3 requires absl-py~=0.10, but you have absl-py 1.0.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.6.3 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.21.6 which is incompatible.
```

And many more similar errors.

How can I fix this?  I am using a Jupyter Notebook in Kaggle so maybe there is a special way to install packages in a Kaggle notebook?

Comment: Tensorflow 2.6.3 is quite an old version, so you may need to use a more recent version of Tensorflow or an older version of fastapi if you can't upgrade tf.

Comment: Oh gotcha, shouldn't the command `pip install -Uqq fastai` fetch the latest version of fastai? It has been updated very frequently so I'm sure fastai's tensorflow dependency has to be one of the newest?

Comment: Fastapi does not depend on tf, nor the other way around. The message indicates you installed tf first, and there are conflicts in mutual dependencies. Upgrading tf might be all you need.

Comment: Okay cool, makes sense. How do I do this in a Kaggle Notebook? This is the code that's producing this error https://www.kaggle.com/code/jhoward/saving-a-basic-fastai-model/notebook. Notice you have to click "Show hidden cell" to see the errors.

Comment: I don't use Kaggle notebooks, but it might work with the same syntax, `!pip install -U tensorflow`. Be ready for further dependency issues, this is the kinda of game that sometimes takes a while to resolve to a fully compatible dependency set.